# Hoisting in javascript along with global variable

Tags: javascript, hoisting

The below code gives an output of `undefined`. I was of the impression that all variable and function declarations are hoisted to the top of their scope and so `b` should now be at the top the scope before calling `a()`. However, I still get `undefined` as my output?

```js
a()

var b = 5;
function a() {
  console.log(b)
}
```

Comment: The _declarations_ are hoisted, not the initializations

Comment: Here's a good read on why you are seeing undefined: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/2nd-ed/scope-closures/ch4.md

Answer (score 5):

You misunderstand how hoisting works. It doesn't hoist the *assignment*, it only hoists the *declaration*. Your code is equivalent to the following:

```
var b; // undefined
function a(){
 console.log(b)
}
a();
b = 5;
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes the variable declaration is hoisted, but the value is not set on `b`. The code looks like this

```js
var b
function a(){
 console.log(b)
}
a()
b = 5;
```

Answer (score 2):

Hoisting means the variables will be *created* “at the top” - but it does not change anything about the time the *value assignment* happens, the `b = 5` part still happens when execution reaches the part where it’s written. So if you call `a()` before that, `b` *exists*, but has not gotten any value assigned yet … hence, `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

You are using a function declaration to create a function. So function declaration is also hoisted so they are being used before declaring.